# Ellipse2D draws with poor accuracy

Tags: java, geometry, ellipse

I'm making an application about space physics, so I do lots with orbits. Naturally, I encounter the `Ellipse2D.Double` to draw my orbits on the screen.

Whenever my JPanel refreshes, I draw the orbit of a body using an Ellipse2D, as well as the body itself with a different method.

Essentially, I discovered that when numbers get very large (whether it be the size of the orbits get large or the visualization is zoomed in very far), the position of the body and the Ellipse2D do not line up.

I calculate the position of the body using a conversion from polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates, and I leave the math for the Ellipse2D up to the `geom` package.

---

Take a look at this code sample. It's the most self-contained version of my problem that I can make, since scale of the circle has to be very large:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EllipseDemo extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(new EllipseDemo());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // These values allow for a very zoomed in view of a piece of the circle
        BigDecimal[] circleCenter = { new BigDecimal(-262842.5), new BigDecimal(-93212.8) };
        BigDecimal circleRadius = new BigDecimal(279081.3);

        // Draw the circle at the given center, with the given width and height
        // x = centerx - radius, y = centery - radius, w = h = radius * 2
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(circleCenter[0].subtract(circleRadius).doubleValue(),
                circleCenter[1].subtract(circleRadius).doubleValue(), circleRadius.multiply(new BigDecimal(2)).doubleValue(),
                circleRadius.multiply(new BigDecimal(2)).doubleValue()));

        // Get a rectangular conversion of a point on the circle at this angle
        BigDecimal angle = new BigDecimal(0.34117696217);
        BigDecimal[] rectangular = convertPolarToRectangular(new BigDecimal[] {
                circleRadius, angle });

        // Draw a line from the center of the circle to the point
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(circleCenter[0].doubleValue(), circleCenter[1].doubleValue(),
                circleCenter[0].add(rectangular[0]).doubleValue(), circleCenter[1]
                        .add(rectangular[1]).doubleValue()));
    }

    public BigDecimal[] convertPolarToRectangular(BigDecimal[] polar) {
        BigDecimal radius = polar[0];
        BigDecimal angle = polar[1];
        BigDecimal x = radius.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.cos(angle.doubleValue())));
        BigDecimal y = radius.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.sin(angle.doubleValue())));
        return new BigDecimal[] { x, y };
    }
}
```

The code above essentially draws a circle on the screen very far away with a large radius. I've picked the dimension so that a piece of the circle is visible in the small window.

Then it draws a line from the center of the circle to a point on the circle that's visible in the window: I picked an angle that was visible on the window and used geometry to convert that angle and the radius of the circle into rectangular coordinates.

This is what the program displays:

[image: The window display]

Notice that the line doesn't actually end up touching the ellipse. Now, I decided I had to find out whether it was the point I calculated or the ellipse that were incorrect. I did the math on my calculator, and found that the line was correct, and the ellipse incorrect:

[image]

Considering that the calculator is probably not wrong, I am led to believe the Ellipse2D is not drawing correctly. However, I tried many other angles, and this is the pattern I found:

[image: Not to scale - it must be much bigger]

And *that* leads me to believe the calculations are somehow wrong.

So that's my problem. Should I be using something other than Ellipse2D? Maybe Ellipse2D is not accurate enough? I used BigDecimals in my code sample because I thought it would give me more precision - is that the wrong approach? My ultimate goal is to be able to calculate the rectangular position of a point on an ellipse at a specific angle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see this error because Ellipse2D is approximated by four cubic curves. To make sure just take a look at its path iterator defining shape border: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/geom/EllipseIterator.java#187

To improve quality we should approximate ellipse by higher number of cubic curves. Here is an extention of standard java implementation with changeable number of segments:

```
class BetterEllipse extends Ellipse2D.Double {
    private int segments;

    public BetterEllipse(int segments, double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        super(x, y, w, h);
        this.segments = segments;
    }

    public int getSegments() {
        return segments;
    }

    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(final AffineTransform affine) {
        return new PathIterator() {
            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public void next() {
                index++;
            }

            @Override
            public int getWindingRule() {
                return WIND_NON_ZERO;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDone() {
                return index > getSegments() + 1;
            }

            @Override
            public int currentSegment(double[] coords) {
                int count = getSegments();
                if (index > count)
                    return SEG_CLOSE;
                BetterEllipse ellipse = BetterEllipse.this;
                double x = ellipse.getCenterX() + Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * index / count) * ellipse.getWidth() / 2;
                double y = ellipse.getCenterY() + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * index / count) * ellipse.getHeight() / 2;
                if (index == 0) {
                    coords[0] = x;
                    coords[1] = y;
                    if (affine != null)
                        affine.transform(coords, 0, coords, 0, 1);
                    return SEG_MOVETO;
                }
                double x0 = ellipse.getCenterX() + Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (index - 2) / count) * ellipse.getWidth() / 2;
                double y0 = ellipse.getCenterY() + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (index - 2) / count) * ellipse.getHeight() / 2;
                double x1 = ellipse.getCenterX() + Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (index - 1) / count) * ellipse.getWidth() / 2;
                double y1 = ellipse.getCenterY() + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (index - 1) / count) * ellipse.getHeight() / 2;
                double x2 = x;
                double y2 = y;
                double x3 = ellipse.getCenterX() + Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (index + 1) / count) * ellipse.getWidth() / 2;
                double y3 = ellipse.getCenterY() + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (index + 1) / count) * ellipse.getHeight() / 2;
                double x1ctrl = x1 + (x2 - x0) / 6;
                double y1ctrl = y1 + (y2 - y0) / 6;
                double x2ctrl = x2 + (x1 - x3) / 6;
                double y2ctrl = y2 + (y1 - y3) / 6;
                coords[0] = x1ctrl;
                coords[1] = y1ctrl;
                coords[2] = x2ctrl;
                coords[3] = y2ctrl;
                coords[4] = x2;
                coords[5] = y2;
                if (affine != null)
                    affine.transform(coords, 0, coords, 0, 3);
                return SEG_CUBICTO;
            }

            @Override
            public int currentSegment(float[] coords) {
                double[] temp = new double[6];
                int ret = currentSegment(temp);
                for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++)
                    coords[i] = (float)temp[i];
                return ret;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And here is how you can use it in your code instead of standard one (I use 100 segments here):

```
    g2d.draw(new BetterEllipse(100, circleCenter[0].subtract(circleRadius).doubleValue(),
            circleCenter[1].subtract(circleRadius).doubleValue(), circleRadius.multiply(new BigDecimal(2)).doubleValue(),
            circleRadius.multiply(new BigDecimal(2)).doubleValue()));
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much.